# Como integrar o bootstrap num projecto em php no dreamweaver cs5.5?

Tags: php, bootstrap, dreamweaver

Estou com dificuldades de integrar o bootstrap no dreamweaver. Para melhor percepção, postarei o código.

**header.php:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>CRUD EM PHP COM PDO OOP USANDO BOOTSTRAP</title>
 <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
 
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com" title='Programming Blog'>Coding Cage</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/CRUD">CRUD</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/PDO">PDO</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/jQuery">jQuery</a>
        </div>
 
    </div>
</div>
```

**footer.php:**

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>tutorial !</strong> <a href="http://www.codingcage.com/">Coding Cage</a>!
 </div>
</div>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**dbconfig.php:**

```
<?php
    $DB_host = "localhost";
    $DB_user = "root";
    $DB_pass = "";
    $DB_name = "dbpdo";

    try
    {
        $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host{$DB_host}; dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
        $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    include_once 'class.crud.php';
    $crud = new crud($DB_con); 
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
    <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <a href="add-data.php" class="btn btn-large btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Gravar</a>
    </div><!--container-->

    <div class="clearfix"></div><br />

    <div class="container">
        <table class='table table-border table-responsive'>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Sobrenome</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Ação</th>            
            </tr>
            <?php
                $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios";
                $record_per_page=3;
                $newquery=$crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
                $crud->dataview($newquery);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" align="center">
                    <div class="pagination-wrap">
                        <?php $crud->paginglink($query,$record_per_page); ?>

                    </div><!--pagination-wrap-->                
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </div><!--container-->

    <?php include_once 'footer.php';?>
```

**Como resultado tenho isso:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Penso que possa ter algum problema no fato de vc estar instanciando a variável `$record_per_page=3` e passando para a função na linha seguinte outra variável `$records_per_page`. Tente remover o 's' da segunda para ver se funciona.

Comment: O problema é que nem traz os artifícios do bootstrap.

Comment: Olhe no console do navegador se a chamada do bootstrap não está retornando 404. Pode ser que o caminho esteja incorreto. Dá uma conferida.

Comment: Como faço isso? Ainda sou novo na programação web.

Comment: Com a página aberta, aperte F12 ou então clique com o botão direito em qualquer lugar da página > Inspecionar elemento. Depois disso vai abrir uma janela com várias abas. Clique em 'Console' e recarregue a página. Veja se vai aparecer alguma notificação de erro do parecido com `[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found ...]`.  Ou então, clique na aba Network, que você verá todas as requisições que sua página está fazendo e veja se a referência do bootstrap não aparece com código `404`.

Comment: Ok. Apareceu o erro 404. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Então, agora que sabemos que é problema de caminho até os arquivos do Bootstrap, vc vai precisar colocar links das referências apontando para o lugar certo. Dê uma lida melhor sobre caminhos relativos [aqui](http://www.nce.ufrj.br/ginape/cursohtml/conteudo/ligacoes/absrel.htm). Depois de consertar o caminho. O bootstrap deve aparecer normalmente. Outra possibilidade é usar o CDN do bootstrap, que corta a necessidade de colocá-lo na sua árvore de diretórios, leia mais [aqui](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: Já fiz das duas formas, baixei novamente o bootstrap a partir do link que me forneceu, copiei o link CDN, nem de um nem de outro jeito deu certo. Quanto ao caminho normal, no dreamweaver quando digito "link href", clico na opção "browse" e coloco o referido ficheiro.

Comment: Consegui, criando um novo documento com a estrutura do html 5.

Comment: Feliz por ter conseguido!

Comment: Muito feliz. Obrigado irmão!